# Create a thumbnail with PHP

Tags: php, image

I have a page which lists a load of portfolios.

I am trying to write a script which will look in a specific folder of images (the projects image folder) for a image called portfolio.jpg.  When this image is found the image would be resized to a specific dimension keeping its filename the same.

Then obviously the next time this script is run it would check the file has been resized and if so just do nothing...

Has anyone got any clue on where to start with something like this?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: and you want that we code it for you?

Comment: No just a helpful hint like below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look at: http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/, http://davidwalsh.name/create-image-thumbnail-php, ...

Answer (score 0):

Easy with [Thumbnailer](http://freelogic.pl/thumbnailer):

```
<?php
require 'Thumbnailer.php';

$thumb=new Thumbnailer("portfolio.jpg");
$thumb->thumbFixed(120,80)->save("portfolio.jpg");
?>
```